# Is it possible to add a new widget in existing Eclipse RCP view

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to create an eclipse plugin for an Eclipse RCP application. Is it possible to add a new widget in one of the existing views.
Currently, the RCP application has a view which extends commonNavigator and it draws a tree inside the view. Now, can I write a plug-in (independent from this RCP application), which can  add a new widget inside this view?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can. What have you already tried, and what confuses you about it?

Comment: Thanks blgt for your reply. I have created a separate view to hold the treeviewer, however, I didn't get any hint on adding a widget on an existing view. I tried to get the view  from IWorkbenchPage, however, I am not sure if it helps to add new widgets in the existing view. It would be very helpful if you could provide me some links which explain the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `createPartControl` method.

```
class MyView extends CommonNavigator {
    // ...
    // private Button myButton;

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        // Call the parent method so the UI controls of
        // CommonNavigator are correctly created.
        super.createPartControl(parent);

        // Add your own widgets here. Below is just an example.
        myButton = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Depending on where you want to add the new widget, you might want to call `super.createPartControl(parent);` after adding your widgets.